# Modified list input using dsd

Tags: sas

I am reading the [Language Reference: Concepts](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1w749t788cgi2n1txpuccsuqtro.htm); and it mentioned i can use ~(tilde) to deal with character values that has delimiters within character values.

And following is the example code

```
data scores;
    infile datalines dsd;
    input name : $9. Score1-score3 Team ~ $25. div $;
    datalines;
Smith,12,22,46,"Green Hornets, Atlanta",AAA 
Mitchel,23,19,25,"High Volts, Portland",AAA 
Jones,09,17,54,"Vulcans, Las Vegas",AA 
run;
```

I am wonder why there is problem if i comment out the infile statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~ Tilde is required to to treat single quotation marks, double quotation marks, and delimiters in character values in a special way. This format modifier reads delimiters within quoted character values as characters instead of as delimiters and retains the quotation marks when the value is written to a variable.
Why this is needed, because SAS has reserved certain delimiters for it's own functioning i.e. single quotation marks, double quotation marks are used to represent strings, when you want SAS to treat these quotation marks differently you have to tell explicitly it to SAS using - Tilde (~)

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000144370.htm

SAS can only automatically recognize single blank as delimiter and it cannot automatically recognize , as delimiter.You would have to explicitly tell it to SAS. In your case you have used the option dsd which does three things for you.

(i) It automatically by default take , as your delimiter. If you want to provide any other delimiter, you would have to specifically tell it to SAS then using dlm= option.

(ii) SAS treats two consecutive delimiters as a missing value and removes quotation marks from character values

(iii)specifies that when data values are enclosed in quotation marks, delimiters within the value are treated as character data

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm

Answer (score 1):

You also remove the DSD option which specified that the delimiter is a comma. Otherwise the expected delimiter is a space.

You don't need the tilde (~) to read the team variable correctly, but you do need it to include the quotation marks.

> DSD (delimiter-sensitive data)
>   specifies that when data values are enclosed in quotation marks, delimiters within the value are treated as character data. The DSD option changes how SAS treats delimiters when you use LIST input and sets the default delimiter to a comma. When you specify DSD, SAS treats two consecutive delimiters as a missing value and removes quotation marks from character values.
>
> Interaction: Use the DELIMITER= or DLMSTR= option to change the delimiter.
>
> Tip:Use the DSD option and LIST input to read a character value that contains a delimiter within a string that is enclosed in quotation marks. The INPUT statement treats the delimiter as a valid character and removes the quotation marks from the character string before the value is stored. **Use the tilde (~) format modifier to retain the quotation marks.**

Comment: i thought it should be the statement to indicate dlm=',', then what is the difference between dlm and dsd?